# relacionar listas en prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

tengo un problema donde tengo que meter a diversas familias dentro de una lista que representa a su respectiva mesa, la familia F no puede estar con la S en la misma mesa pero sin con la familia R,
la familia G tiene que estar junta con la W y la A , pero no con la P, la familia P quiere estar con la G y la familia M no puede estar con S. hasta ahora lo que llevo es esto :

```
solve_gala(Solution):-
    %solucion una lista hecha con lista en formato miembro[apellido,categoria (hay
%ejemplo Mama Faraon pertenece a faraon y mesa %]

Solution=[[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],1],
        [[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],2],
        [[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],3],
%faraon F
member([[faraonpapa,F1],_],Solution),
member([[faraonmama,F2],_],Solution),
member([[faraonhijo,F3],_],Solution),
member([[faraonhija,F4],_],Solution),
%robot r
member([[robot,R],_],Solution),
       
%metalheads m
member([[dikinson,M1],_],Solution),
member([[harris,M2],_],Solution),
member([[dio,M3],_],Solution),
member([[summers,M4],_],Solution),
%parsons p
member([[parsons,P],_],Solution),
%gilmur g
member([[gilmur,G],_],Solution),
%sacerdote s
member([[sacerdote,S],_], Solution),
%Wilson w
member([[wilson,W],_],Solution),
%akerferd a
member([[akerferd,A],_],Solution),
%griegos
 member([[demis,G1],_],Solution),
 member([[vengelis,G2],_],Solution),
 member([[mikis,G3],_],Solution),


  %CONDICIONES
F1 is F2,
F2 is F3,
F3 is F4,
F4 is R,
G1 is G2, G2 is G3,
W is A, 
A \== P,
P is G,
M1 is M2, M2 is M3, M3 is M4,
S \== M1,
S \== R.
```

Al correrlo me da este error:

> No permission to call sandboxed `get_flag(_1676,_1678)'
>
> Reachable from:
>
> ```
> system:flag(A,B,C)
>
> system:consult(A)
>
> [A|B]
>
> solve_gala(A)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en estas líneas:

```
Solution=[[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],1],
        [[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],2],
        [[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],3],
```

Si te fijas la unificación con la variable Solution solamente es con `[[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],1]`. Luego lo que queda, que es sintáctamente válido es `[[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],2]` y luego el resto del código.
Pero `[...]` se utiliza para [consultar](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=consult/1) más código prolog desde el sistema de archivos.

La solución en tu caso seguramente sea agregar unos paréntesis rectos extra:

```
Solution=[[[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],1],
        [[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],2],
        [[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],[_,_],3]],
```